switching to iframe getting error: Message: no such element: element not found
I'm trying to remove a pop-up inside an iframe that is inside a div. I have to find the close button and click. My code is able to locate the iframe and is printing the iframe before switching to it and is shown empty. It is the same iframe that contains the pop up. I'm getting error while switching to it.
iframe:
<div id="sp_message_container_964490" style="display: block;">
<iframe src="https://cdn.privacy-mgmt.com/index.html
message_id=
964490&amp;consentUUID=undefined&amp;
 preload_message=true&amp;hasCsp=true&amp;version=v1&amp;
  consent_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.privacy- 
  mgmt.com%2Fconsent%2Ftcfv2&amp;mms_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.privacy- 
  mgmt.com%2Fmms%2Fv2&amp;
 consentLanguage=en" id="sp_message_iframe_964490" title="SP Consent Message">... 
</iframe>
</div>

inside iframe:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <title>Notice Message App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum- 
 scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover">

...............
<button title="Essential cookies only" aria-label="Essential cookies only" 
class="message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_13" 
style="opacity: 1; padding: 10px 20px; margin: 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: 
rgb(49, 87, 161); border-radius: 4px; border-style: solid; font-size: 14px; font- 
weight: 700; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;, helvetica, sans-serif; width: auto; background: 
rgb(49, 87, 161);">Essential cookies only</button>
................
}</style></body></html>

I have to access this button within the html.
My code:
    divs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
    for div in divs:
        if "message" in div.get_attribute("id"):
            iframe = div.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
            # for iframe in iframes:
            try:
                print("beofre switching to iframe", iframe.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
                driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
                print("switched to iframe", iframe.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
                content = driver.page_source
                if 'consent' in content.lower():
                    handle_popups(driver)
                    return True
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"error switching to iframe {e}")
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            return False

How can I switch to the iframe and why is it printed empty?

I used selenium webdriver wait for iframe to be available and switch to iframe with a generic xpath containing the keyword and click the close button using my defined handle_popups function.
My new code:
try:
    iframe_path = "//iframe[contains(translate(@title, 
   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 
   'consent')]"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 
    5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, 
    iframe_path)))
    handle_popups(driver)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    return True
 except Exception as e:
    print(f"error finding iframes: {e}")
    return False

